$\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ is unimodular
I'd like to prove the well-known result that $G = \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ is unimodular, using elementary results, i.e. without reductive groups.
Some definitions: as a locally compact group, $G$ admits left and right Haar measures.
The modular character $\Delta \colon G \to \mathbb R_{>0}$ measures the discrepancy of between left and right Haar measures.
$G$ is unimodular iff $\Delta = 1$, i.e. left and right Haar measures coincide.
I know the following:

$\Delta$ restricted to abelian subgroups of $G$ are obviously trivial.
$\Delta$ restricted to the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ is trivial since $\Delta$ is a group homomorphism.
$\Delta$ restricted to compact subgroups $K$ of $G$ is trivial since $\Delta(K)$ is a compact subgroup of $\mathbb R_{>0}$, and hence necessarily $\Delta(K) = 1$.
This applies in particular to $K = \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb Z_p)$, which is compact, open and closed in $G$.

My idea was that since we know that $\Delta([G,G]) = 1$, then $\Delta$ must factor through the abelianisation $G/[G,G]$. From here on out, it is not so easy to determine whether $\bar \Delta \colon G/[G,G] \to \mathbb R_{>0}$ is again a modular character (it must be generally wrong, for otherwise, all locally compact groups were unimodular).
I also tried to follow this answer on Math Overflow.
However, I have trouble understanding the proof; in particular:

why $G / Z(G) [G,G]$ is compact where $Z(G)$ is the centre of $G$, and
why the subgroup generated by $[G,G]$, $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb Z_p)$ and $Z(G)$ is of finite index in $G$, and how this will help us.


Sadly I'm not really familiar with the p-adic setting... maybe you could try to copy my proof here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4921311/721316 which is at least for $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ quite "elementary". All you need to do is find the Cartan decomposition for $GL(n, \mathbb Q_p)$ in an elementary way but I believe this can be done similarly as the classical polar decomposition of matrices (?) Don't quote me on that however...

First note that the commutator subgroup of $G$ is $[G,G] = \mathrm{SL}_n(\Bbb Q_p)$, and that the centre of $G$ is $Z(G) = \{\lambda \mathrm{id} : \lambda \in \Bbb Q_p^\times\} \cong \Bbb Q_p^\times$. As stated in the post, we know that $\Delta(K) = \Delta([G,G]) = \Delta(Z(G)) = 1$. Then the subgroup $U := K \cdot Z(G) \cdot [G,G]$ of $G$ is open since $K$ is, and we have $\Delta(U) = 1$.
We want to show that the index $[G:U]$ is finite. Observe that $\det$ induces a homeomorphism $G / [G,G] = \mathrm{GL}_n(\Bbb Q_p) / \mathrm{SL}_n(\Bbb Q_p) \cong \Bbb Q_p^\times$. Under this homeomorphism, $Z(G) [G,G] / [G,G]$ corresponds to $(\Bbb Q_p^\times)^n$ (i.e. $\det(\lambda \mathrm{id}) = \lambda^n$). Hence $G' := G / Z(G) [G,G] \cong \Bbb Q_p^\times / (\Bbb Q_p^\times)^n$. Using the description $\Bbb Q_p^\times \cong \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z_p^\times$, the last group is homeomorphic to $(\Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z) \times \Bbb Z_p^\times / (\Bbb Z_p^\times)^n$. Note that $\Bbb Z_p^\times / (\Bbb Z_p^\times)^n$ is compact because it is the image of the compact group $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ under the quotient map. Therefore $G'$ is compact. As $\coprod_{\bar x \in G' / (U / Z(G) [G,G])} x U / Z(G) [G,G]$ is an open cover of $G'$, it follows that $G' / (U / Z(G) [G,G]) \cong G/U$ is finite, as desired.
Now write $G$ as a finite disjoint union $G = \coprod_{x \in G/U} xU$. As $\Delta(U) = 1$, the image of $G$ is the finite subgroup $\Delta(G) = \{\Delta(x) : x \in G/U\}$ of $\Bbb R_{>0}$. This forces $\Delta(G) = 1$ to be trivial (if $r \in \Delta(G) \setminus \{1\}$ exists, then also $r^\Bbb Z \subseteq \Delta(G)$, which is infinite).
